# Time zone used for Oracle Date field

Tags: oracle, date, timezone

TL;DR - am I correct in thinking there is no way to determine the timezone used for a given record of a Date field when the server's time zone was changed at some point in the past?

A factory control system was designed to use UTC server (not Oracle) time so all Date columns were UTC. At some point in the past they changed the server time to local. Now years later, they would like the apps to display the correct date. Without knowing the date the change occurred, is there a way to `SELECT` so all Date records would be correct? I think I can either make the "modern" records correct or the pre-change records correct but not both unless I know when that happened. Since it was a Windows OS change, I don't think even the alert log would help assuming they haven't trimmed it at some point, but it's not easy to get any info or server access from them anyway. It had been 10g and is now 12c.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Moving on. Next question: Is there a way to infer, from the data you have, WHEN the switch may have occurred? Something along the following lines (which may have absolutely nothing to do with your business). The system records when people arrive to work and when they leave. Looking at the data, you see that most people arrived at 3 AM (probably UTC then, right?) until March 15 2010, but after that most people seem to be arriving at 8 AM. Then you may guess that the switch happened on March 16, 2010.

Comment: Yes, if I wanted to find out bad enough I could try to find when there was an abnormal gap. I suspect it would have occurred during a shutdown (i.e., holiday) though.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  Oracle's `DATE` datatype is timezone agnostic.  If you want to store timezone info in the database, use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` datatype.